# Rearrangement of objects in arraylist

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

```
public void go()
{
    ArrayList<String> fruits = new ArrayList<>();

    fruits.add("pear");
    fruits.add("pineapple");
    fruits.add("oranges");
    fruits.add("banana");
    fruits.add("apple");

    for(String str: fruits)
    {
         if(str.contains("apple"))
         {   /* I would like anything containing 'apple' 
          * i.e. apple & pineapple to be placed on top of the array*/   }
    }
    for(String str: fruits)
    {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the above code if printed as normal, would result in

pear, pineapple, oranges, banana, apple.

How can I sort this array, in the way that anything with apple would be sorted alphabetically first, and those that are not should remain the same. i.e, the output should looks like:

apple, pineapple, pear, oranges, banana.

Is there even a possible way to go around it??

Comment: I am thinking of, searching through the entire array to find the string that contain e.g. apple, then pick them out and put them into a new arraylist. Next, I would sort the new array, and then put into into a third array first. next up, what's remaining in the very 1st array, shall be added into the 3rd array. do I make sense?

Comment: @RohitJain, because pineAPPLE does contain 'apple'. Thats why it is sorted alphabetically with apple. Of course, this is just my snippet code as my orginal code and array is way larger. But that's the idea I am bringing across, of course.

Comment: Now I've reread your question, that's exactly what I'd do - but using lists, not arrays.

Comment: Thank you everyone for all the useful help here. I figured that since I am not that familiar with Comparator class and that splitting my list  into 2 list would be much easier to implement and understand, I decided to go with that approach. Of course, I learned much more concept that I had expected. I appreciate all the help here. :)

Answer (score 4):

I would split the list into two: items that contain `apple`, and items that don't. Then sort the apple-containing list, and then append the non-apple-containing list.

```
List<String> apples = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> nonApples = new ArrayList<>();
for (String fruit : fruits) {
  if (fruit.contains("apple")) {
    apples.add(fruit);
  } else {
    nonApples.add(fruit);
  }
}
Collections.sort(apples);
apples.addAll(nonApples);
// apples now contains what you want. Of course, it's now misnamed :)
```

As an alternative for the last few lines, creating a copy of the apples-only list:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(apples);
Collections.sort(result);
result.addAll(nonApples);
```

This is all pretty much equivalent to JB Nizet's approach, except it only checks for apple-containment once per item, instead of going through the original list twice. Unless your real check is really expensive, it's unlikely that this will be a performance bottleneck, so use whichever approach you prefer.

It's not clear whether you need the results to be in your *original* list, or whether it's fine to have a new list with the result.

If you need to put them in your original list, you can always use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
  fruits.set(i, result.get(i));
}
```

The approaches using `Collections.sort` which rely on it being stable are interesting - but I personally feel they're less clear than this approach.

Comment: FYI: I chose not to have a list for nonApples because my guess is that it will contain almost all the elements of the original list, and that iterating through the original list a second time would be faster and consume less memory. Of course, it the actual check is more complex than a simple contains() call, or if most of the elements contain apple, your solution is better.

Comment: @JBNizet: That's why it's good for there to be both answers :) I wonder how efficiently this could be done in-place, maintaining the order of non-apples while moving apples to the front, then sorting the sublist...

Comment: Indeed. I would bet on bad performance, due to the numerous array copies needed each time an apple moves from its location to the front of the list.

Answer (score 2):

A Comparator is not the right answer. Here's how I would do it:

```
List<String> containingApple = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : list) {
    if (s.contains("apple")) {
        containingApple.add(s);
    }
}
Collections.sort(containingApple);
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
result.addAll(containingApple);
for (String s : list) {
    if (!s.contains("apple")) {
        result.add(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that it *can* be done with a `Comparator` and `Collections.sort`, because `Collections.sort` is stable - something I'd personally forgotten. It's not how I'd do it, but it should work...

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `Collections.sort()` method with a custom one-time comparator like this:

```
Collections.sort(fruits, new Comparator<String>(){

        @Override
        public int compare(String arg0, String arg1) {
            if (arg0.contains("apple") && arg1.contains("apple")) {
                return arg0.compareTo(arg1);
            }
            else if (arg0.contains("apple") && !arg1.contains("apple")){
                return -1;
            }
            else if (!arg0.contains("apple") && arg1.contains("apple")){
                return 1;
            } else return 0;
        } });
```

Please note that the final statement of `else return 0` is crucial in order to ensure that other values not containing "apple" will not be sorted.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite an ugly piece of code, but it does the trick.
The idea is to implement a `Comparator` in a way that if both strings contain `apple` they are compared lexicographically, if only one of them does, it's deemed "smaller", and if neither do, they are deemed "equal" (i.e., we return 0, and do not change the order).

```
public class AppleStringComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (o1.contains("apple")) {
            if (o2.contains("apple")) {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        } else {
            if (o2.contains("apple")) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MainClass {
    public void go() {
        // The example code from the OP
        ArrayList<String> fruits = new ArrayList<>();

        fruits.add("pear");
        fruits.add("pineapple");
        fruits.add("oranges");
        fruits.add("banana");
        fruits.add("apple");

        Collections.sort(fruits, new AppleStringComparator());

        // Print out the result, for completeness' sake:
        System.out.println(fruits);
}
```

Comment: Ah... had forgotten that `Collections.sort` is stable. Interesting.

Comment: This comment must be worth a badge or something `-)